# Расширение для Хром! Как получить HTML объект по клику в расширении через chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, extension

Пытаюсь получить сохраненный объект в chrome.storage, по клику в носом расширении, но получается null. Причем если я его получаю сразу же, то все ок, но если по клику из расширения то выходит null. Буду благодарен кто подскажет, что не так

Манифест

```html
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "google extension",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "google extension",
  "permissions": [
          "storage"
        ],
   "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html" //код самого виджета будет лежать тут
  },
  
  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
  "icons": {},
  "content_scripts": [{
  "js": ["popup.js"],
  "matches": ["http://exemple.com/*"]
  
}]

}
```

popup.html - сам Html расширения

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test1</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Action:</h1>
<button id="click">Add To Friend List</button>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
var el = document.getElementById('click');//отслеживаем клик в расширении

var value = document.getElementById('errr');//объект на странице 

chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
     console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
   }); //записываем в chrome.storage
  
   chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
      alert('Value currently is ' + result.key);
    });//все ок, получаем объект HTML, хотя ниже при вызове уже получаем null
    

if (el){//если кликнули в нашем расширении
 el.onclick = function() {
     chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
       alert('Value currently is ' + result.key);
     });//получаем null хотя должны получить объект HTML
     
   };
 
}
```

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'])` точно не просто `'key'` ?

Comment: Брал у них с оф мануалов https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: я не уверен, но проверьте на всякий =) и `result.key` без `.key`

Comment: 1. не получилось - popup.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: сhrome is not defined
    at popup.js:16. 2. Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Проблема что все это прекрасно работает если я не прошу это  по клику в расширении, как только я запрашиваю переменную из стореджа при клике в расширении, выдает null

Comment: @IlyaT вы там ниже не прочитали, там написано `string or array`, у меня выглядит вот так(без sync) `chrome.storage.local.get( "mainHost", function(s) { /*...*/ } );` и все прекрасно работает

Comment: Имеете ввиду что не может храниться объект? посмотрите пожалуйста\. я добавил код в popup.js и вот если записывать и запрашивать объект в стеке то все ок, но как только запрашиваем объект по событию приходит null.